# Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected n fields in line j, saw k fix by ignoring extra columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a (bad) csv file that looks something like this:

```
model, height, strength
1, 124.5, 63
2, 160.4, 85
3, 144.6, 94, 88
4, 122.5, 36, 29
5, 132, 22
6, 140.6, 46, 200, 0.8
```

I would like to create a dataframe that takes all lines, but ignores any "extra" column values, so it would take all 6 of these lines with columns `model`, `height` and `strength`, but ignore the values of `88`,`29`, `200` and `0.8` on lines 3, 4, 6 and 6 respectively.

I can work around the specific lines using `error_bad_lines=False` in `pd.read_csv`, but this just straight ignores those lines, which I don't want to do.

So is there a way in pandas to do this?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

Read the file with any other seperator:

```
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO("""model, height, strength
1, 124.5, 63
2, 160.4, 85
3, 144.6, 94, 88
4, 122.5, 36, 29
5, 132, 22
6, 140.6,46, 200, 0.8"""),sep='|')
```

**Method1**:
Split the values based on comma and create a a new df and dropna over `axis=1`

```
m=df.iloc[:,0].str.split(',',expand=True).dropna(axis=1)
m.columns=df.columns.str.split(',').tolist()
print(m)
```

---

```
  model  height  strength
0     1   124.5        63
1     2   160.4        85
2     3   144.6        94
3     4   122.5        36
4     5     132        22
5     6   140.6        46
```

**Method2**: after reading with `sep='|'`

```
cols=df.columns.str.split(',')[0]
df=pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:,0].str.split(',').str[:len(cols)].values.tolist(),columns=cols)
```

---

```
  model  height  strength
0     1   124.5        63
1     2   160.4        85
2     3   144.6        94
3     4   122.5        36
4     5     132        22
5     6   140.6        46
```

Answer (score 2):

I will using

```
from pandas.compat import StringIO
dat = """model, height, strength
1, 124.5, 63
2, 160.4, 85
3, 144.6, 94, 88
4, 122.5, 36, 29
5, 132, 22
6, 140.6, 46, 200, 0.8"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(dat), sep=',',header=None,names=range(1,10))
df=df.iloc[:,:3].T.set_index(0).T
df
0 model  height  strength
1     1   124.5        63
2     2   160.4        85
3     3   144.6        94
4     4   122.5        36
5     5     132        22
6     6   140.6        46
```